# Clearing the canvas for each tab in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a complicated gui which is too long to post here. I cannot understand how to clear the graph from a figure in my Tkinter gui. I have a tabbed gui and want to plot a graph in each tab and clear the graph in each tab. When I try and do this I get various different errors to do with canvas. I can understand a figure, an axes, a tab, and a frame, but the canvas seems to be referred to as a synonym for a figure which just seems weird (and probably not correct).

I can't see what the difference is between figure and canvas (are there any?), most articles and answers I have read on here don't seem to cover canvas at all

Matplotlib documentation:
"Figure
The whole figure. The figure keeps track of all the child Axes, a smattering of ‘special’ artists (titles, figure legends, etc), and the canvas. (***Don’t worry too much about the canvas, it is crucial*** as it is the object that actually does the drawing to get you your plot, but as the user it is more-or-less invisible to you). A figure can have any number of Axes, but to be useful should have at least one."

***Code***

```
import tkinter.filedialog
import os
import re
import tkinter as tk                     
from tkinter import ttk 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")  # this is the backend of matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import easygui
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
from scipy.stats import linregress
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)

#=====================================================================
# ROOT FIGURE FOR GUI
#=====================================================================
root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry("600x450") 
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Circle cal drops')
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='OPW') 

tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
tabControl.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)


# TAB 1
# creating a frame (my_frame_1)
my_frame_1 = tk.Frame(tab1, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
my_frame_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

fig = Figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)

def clearPlot():
    fig.clear()
    canvas.draw_idle()


def plotData():
    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 1, 3, 8], marker='.', c='r')
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = my_frame_1)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack()


#create another frame(my_frame_2) 
my_frame_2 = tk.Frame(tab1, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
my_frame_2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
button1_cal = tk.Button(my_frame_2, text = "Clear Plot", command = clearPlot, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button1_cal.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button2_cal = tk.Button(my_frame_2, text = "Plot \nData", command = plotData, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button2_cal.pack(side="top", fill="x" )

# TAB 2
# creating a frame (my_frame_3)
my_frame_3 = tk.Frame(tab2, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
my_frame_3.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

def clearPlotOpw():
    pass

def plotDataOpw():
    fig = Figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 5, 1, 3, 11], marker='o', c='b')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = my_frame_3)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

#create another frame(my_frame_4) 
my_frame_4 = tk.Frame(tab2, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
my_frame_4.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

button1_cal = tk.Button(my_frame_4, text = "Clear Plot", command = clearPlotOpw, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button1_cal.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button2_cal = tk.Button(my_frame_4, text = "Plot \nData", command = plotDataOpw, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button2_cal.pack(side="top", fill="x" )

root.mainloop()
print('\n'*4)
```

*** Desired Outcome ***

being able to clear each plot and re-plot as often as required.

***Traceback when trying to use the clear plot function***

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/tk_gui_grid/basic_08.py", line 48, in clearPlot
    canvas.draw_idle()
NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
```

I know canvas is undefined, but when I define it the plot doesn't get drawn at all.

Comment: Try saying `global canvas` ontop of `plotDataOpw()`  and `plotData()` ?

Comment: I had tried that. It will clear the first plot but not the second (plotDataOpw() ).

Comment: These kinds of problems are always the same: don't create a new `Figure` and `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object every time you execute the function. Create it once outside the function, clear the canvas and plot inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in the end.

```
#MAKE A FIGURE OBJECT
my_figure4 = Figure(figsize = (4, 4), dpi = 100) 

#MAKE A FRAME WIDGET
frame1 = tk.Frame(tab4, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
frame2 = tk.Frame(tab4, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
frame2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

#MAKE A CANVAS OBJECT
my_canvas4 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(my_figure4, master = frame1) # creating the Tkinter canvas containing the Matplotlib figure  

# TURN THE CANVAS OBJECT INTO A CANVAS WIDGET
my_canvas4.get_tk_widget().pack() # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window
my_canvas4.draw()

def plotData():
    plot1 = my_figure4.add_subplot(111) # adding the subplot 
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    plot1.plot(x, y, marker='o', c='y')
    my_canvas4.draw()

def clearPlot():
    my_figure4.clear()
    my_canvas4.draw_idle()
```